# DynamoDB - Querying by sortkey using .NET Object Persistence Model

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cdk

The code bellow works fine but I wonder if this is the right way to query by sortkey using .NET Persistence Model. Examples from [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.QueryScan.html) are using other approach. Just wondering if this is fine too?

```
public async Task<List<Transaction>> GetUserTransactionsAsync(string userEmail, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var operationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
    {
        IndexName = DynamoConstants.TransactionsUserDateIndexName,
        
    };
    var sortKeyValues = new List<object> { start, end };

    return await _dBContext
        .QueryAsync<Transaction>(userEmail, QueryOperator.Between, sortKeyValues,  operationConfig)
        .GetRemainingAsync();
}
```

Global secondary Index:

```
transactionsTable.AddGlobalSecondaryIndex(new GlobalSecondaryIndexProps
{
    IndexName = DynamoConstants.TransactionsUserDateIndexName,
    PartitionKey = new Attribute { Name = nameof(Transaction.UserEmail), Type = AttributeType.STRING },
    SortKey = new Attribute { Name = nameof(Transaction.Date), Type = AttributeType.STRING},
    ReadCapacity = 10,
    WriteCapacity = 10,
    ProjectionType = ProjectionType.ALL
});
```

Model:

```
[DynamoDBTable(DynamoConstants.TransactionsTableName)]
public class Transaction
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    
    // Some attributes
}
```